# Build failed after adding new main file in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, program-entry-point

I am new to NetBeans (switched from Dev) and added a new main file to a project to try to test a few things out (clearly this is not acceptable in NetBeans). Now, even though I've deleted the extra main file, my builds keep failing and I am seeing "No rule to make target `newmain.cpp', needed by`build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'.  Stop" ... so it seems like it's still looking for the extra main file even though I've deleted it. How do I stop this from happening?

UPDATE: found the file and removed it from the project correctly, but deleted the Makefile in the process. How do I recreate the Makefile?

Comment: clean your project and/or manually delete the intermediate files.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried Clean & Build, same issue. I deleted the file in the folder, is there a different way I need to delete the file? I checked in the file explorer, it's no longer there.

Comment: Did you delete the file from your NetBeans project?  That would remove it from the build **and** remove the file itself.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes! That's why I was confused on why it would even be looking for the file. I just tried deleting the Makefile because I thought that would help but I think I have sincerely messed up my entire project now